# "the operation cannot be completed because the dbcontext has been disposed entity framework" error is no var userinfo line

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Error happens on the `var userinfo` line... I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to create a sample project to learn ASP.NET MVC, but got stuck here. I searched other posts with similar errors, but the issue was with not saving .

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel c)
{
    using (db = new DBEntities())
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(c);
        }

    // error happens on this line of code
    var userinfo = db.e_usr.Where(m => m.usr_ename == c.Email && m.usr_pswd == c.Password).FirstOrDefault();

    if (userinfo != null)
    {
        Session["LoginID"] = userinfo.usr_ename;
        Session["LoginUser"] = userinfo.usr_pswd;
        return Redirect("Home/Index");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a **code block** (by specifying `{ .... }`) after your `using` statement. Therefore, the `db` is valid for only the next statement - the check whether your `ModelState` is valid or not. After that, the `db` variable is gone.

Change your code to:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel c)
{
    using (db = new DBEntities())
    {                               // <<<==== add this leading curly brace!
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(c);
        }

        // Simplify your LINQ here - define the condition directly
        // in the ".FirstOrDefault()" method
        var userinfo = db.e_usr.FirstOrDefault(m => m.usr_ename == c.Email && m.usr_pswd == c.Password);

        if (userinfo != null)
        {
             Session["LoginID"] = userinfo.usr_ename;
             Session["LoginUser"] = userinfo.usr_pswd;
             return Redirect("Home/Index");
        }

        return null;
    }             /// <<<==== add these closing curly braces
}
```

Comment: thank u so much.........can u pls guide me a tutorial as to where can i learn n make my project for mvc with entity framework with proper code standards???

Comment: @Adnan: if feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.